# VB.net looping through a split string / replacing

Tags: vb.net, arrays, loops, replace

I'm trying to make a function in VB.net that will loop through an algorithm. I've split the algorithm into an array using the Split command, so I have an array with the values.
I then try to loop through them and replace a # with "Number" where necessary, however VB.net throws an error.
I'm fairly new to VB.net, so I'm unsure why it's doing this.
Algorithms are in the format `A B C D E F 1 2 3 #`

```
Function generate(ByVal alg As String)
    Dim algSplit As String() = alg.Split(" ")
    For Each digit In algSplit
        Dim replacement As String = algSplit(digit).Replace("#", "Number")
        algSplit(digit) = replacement
    Next
    Dim result As String = String.Join("", algSplit)
    MsgBox(result)
End Function
```

### Is there a quick fix?

Question Part 2: I got the loop working; however I broke part of the functionality I was aiming for.

```
Public Function GetRandom(ByVal Min As Integer, ByVal Max As Integer) As Integer
    Dim Generator As System.Random = New System.Random()
    Return Generator.Next(Min, Max)
End Function
Public Function RandLet() As String
    Dim number As Integer = GetRandom(1, 26)
    Dim Alphabet() As String = New String() {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V""W", "X", "Y", "Z"}
    Dim Letter As String = Alphabet(number)
    Return Letter
End Function
Function generate(ByVal alg As String) As String
    Dim algSplit As String() = alg.Split(" "c)

    For index As Int32 = 0 To algSplit.Length - 1
        algSplit(index) = algSplit(index).Replace("#"c, GetRandom(1, 9)).Replace("%"c, RandLet())
    Next
    Dim result As String = String.Join("", algSplit)
    MsgBox(result)
    Return result
End Function
```

End result from `A B C D E F 1 2 3 | L % % % | N # # #` ends up as `ABCDEF123|LXXX|N888`
Essentially, each # and each % are being replaced by the same number instead of a different one each time. I thought that being in a loop this wouldn't happen, what have I missed?

Comment: can you post the error message?

Comment: `Conversion from string "A" to type 'Integer' is not valid.`

Comment: wrap a try-catch around it and then you can show us the EM?

Comment: you're getting the error bc you're using a string as the array indexer in algSplit(digit).  That's now allowed.  That aside, Im not sure what you want to do w/ your code.  Are you just looking to replace "#" with "Number"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably easier with LINQ:

```
Dim value = "A B C D E F 1 2 3 #"
Dim replaced = From digit In value.Split(" "c)
             Select digit.Replace("#"c, "Number")
Dim result = String.Join("", replaced)
```

Your "traditional" approach, corrected:

```
Function generate(ByVal alg As String) As String
    Dim algSplit As String() = alg.Split(" "c)

    For index As Int32 = 0 To algSplit.Length - 1
        algSplit(index) = algSplit(index).Replace("#"c, "Number")
    Next
    Dim result As String = String.Join("", algSplit)
    Return result
End Function
```

1. Methods(Functions in VB) must return something. Your function doesn't return anything, hence add `AS String` at the end.
2. `Split` has several overloads, the one you're using takes a `Char` instead of string, so replace `alg.Split(" ")` with `alg.Split(" "c)`
3. If you want to replace an array value with something other, it's better to you a `For-Loop` instead of a `For-Each` since you need to use the index often (see above)

Comment: I came across another issue using this; so I updated the original question.

Comment: @SatansFate: Pass the random instance to the method since it's inititialized with the current time. That'll produce always the same "random" value when called in a short time.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean - could you elaborate?

Comment: @SatansFate: There are many similar questions on SO, try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-not-working-the-way-i-had-planned-c

Answer (score 2):

You are For-Eaching with a string variable since `digit` is finding "A", which is a string, but you are using it as an index: `algSplit(digit).`.

You can try this instead:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To algSplit.Length - 1
  algSplit(i) = algSplit(i).Replace("#", "Number")
Next
```

If you are just looking at replacing the `#` and the empty spaces, this works, too:

```
alg = alg.Replace(" ", String.Empty).Replace("#", "Number")
```

Comment: This is good, but I was eventually going to replace the # with a random number for each one so I wanted a loop to make sure each was randomised separately.

Answer (score 1):

You are looping on an array of strings.
The foreach on algSplit return a string not an integer.
You can't use that `digit` string as an index into the array

Replace your code with this:

```
Function generate(ByVal alg As String)     
    Dim algSplit As String() = alg.Split(" ")     
    For digit = 0 to algSplit.Length - 1
        Dim replacement As String = algSplit(digit).Replace("#", "Number")         
        algSplit(digit) = replacement     
               ' could be simply written as 
               ' algSplit(digit) = algSplit(digit).Replace("#", "Number")     

    Next     
    Dim result As String = String.Join("", algSplit)     
    ??? .. you should return something here ????
End Function
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Function generate(ByVal alg As String)     
    Dim algSplit As String() = alg.Split(" ")     
    For digit = 0 to algSplit.Length - 1
        Dim replacement As String = algSplit(digit).Replace("#", "Number")         
        algSplit(digit) = replacement     
               ' could be simply written as 
               ' algSplit(digit) = algSplit(digit).Replace("#", "Number")     

    Next     
    Dim result As String = String.Join("", algSplit)     
    ??? .. you should return something here ????
End Function
```